# How to refactor class, where public methods are only getters, to be test unit friendly?

Tags: php, unit-testing

How to refactor class, where public methods are only getters, to be test unit friendly?

How to test this class, what methods to test?

```
class Order
{
    private $em;
    private $orders;
    private $foo;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function prepareOrder($foo)
    {
        $this->setFields($foo);
        $this->doSomething() 
        $this->prepareRepository();
    }

    private function setFields($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    private function doSomething()
    {
        //do something with $this->foo
    }


    private function prepareRepository()
    {
        //use $this->foo;  
        $this->orders = $this->em->getRepository(..)->findBy(..);
    }


    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }
}
```

Comment: let's start from: what `Order` should do? What's its responsibility?

Comment: to return repository.

Comment: great, then test that.

Comment: what if instead above I say "manipulate input data, and return repository"? also test this manipulation methods? In fact these manipulation methods are main thing in this class https://gist.github.com/sruj/dd36dc2527edb14d1e5a96609352df3a . Anyway is it makes sense to unit test method with Doctrine::getRepository() ?

Comment: You want to use testing to help you make better design. Your code is doing to many different things. Google ``single responsibility principle`` then split your class up. Then you will know what to test (or better yet try testing it first (TDD)).